# how can I loop an array based on its length

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

My input is `'[ Company_A,Company_B,Company_C]'` which is a string and I already to use

```
$array = explode(',', (trim($filters->input('provider'), '[]')));
```

to convert it.

**My Filter**

```
public $array;
public $i, $j;

public static function apply(Request $filters, $size, $bonus)
{
if ($filters->has('provider') && trim($filters->input('provider')) != "") {
        $bonus->whereHas('bonusCompany', function ($query) use ($filters) {
            $array = explode(',', (trim($filters->input('provider'), '[]')));
            $j = count($array);
            echo count($array);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
                $query->where('providers', 'like', ['%' . $array[$i] . '%']);
                echo $array[$i];
                echo $filters->input('provider');
            }
        });
```

I'm trying to get the data that `providers`equal to `$array[0]`,`$array[1]`,`$array[2]`which is `Company_A,Company_B,Company_C`. My `providers` field is json format so I use `like` and `%` to match it. In doing that I using a for loop to do that but somehow I can't get any data.

**Output**

[image]

As you can see I tried to print out the `count($array)` and the value is `3`.
and `echo $array[$i]` = `Company_A,Company_B,Company_C`
Which is match with my input.

I tried to change this line `$query->where('providers', 'like', ['%' . $array[$i] . '%']);` to   `$query->where('providers', 'like', ['%' . $array[0] . '%']);`

and I get all the data that `provider` = `Company_A` which is my first input(so I assume my codes is works.
But why the `$array[$i]` is not working?

I have printed out my `echo $query->toSql();`
and this is what I got

```
select * from `bonus_Company` where `bonuses`.`id` = `bonus_Company`.`fk_bonus_id` and `providers` = ?
select * from `bonus_Company` where `bonuses`.`id` = `bonus_Company`.`fk_bonus_id` and `providers` = ? and `providers` = ?
select * from `bonus_Company` where `bonuses`.`id` = `bonus_Company`.`fk_bonus_id` and `providers` = ? and `providers` = ? and `providers` = ?
```

the correct query should be

```
select * from `bonus_Company` where `bonuses`.`id` = `bonus_Company`.`fk_bonus_id` and (`providers` like ? or `providers` like ?)
```

Comment: You can do in two ways. instead of explode by comma, you can use same string in `in` clause of database query. Or you can use `foreach` instead of `for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {`

Comment: @NaveedRamzan sry, not understand

Comment: question  updated

Comment: I have added answer

Comment: _“My providers field is json format so I use like and % to match it.”_ - outright terrible. Either use the JSON functionality provided by the DBMS - or store the data in a different format / structure. Fishing around in JSON using LIKE isn’t any better than storing good (bad) old classic comma-separated data into single fields.

Comment: `providers = ? And providers = ?` Is weird. You can not have the same column equal multiple distinct values at the same time. Try OR instead of AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is sql database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puQlA.png)

```
$string = "company_A, company_B"; //string of company names you want to search
$array = explode( ",", $string); //convert string to array
$i = 1;    
$qry = "SELECT * from `company` ";
foreach($array as $companyName) {            
        if($i <= 1){
            $qry .= " WHERE `providers` LIKE '%".trim($companyName)."%' ";
        } else {
            $qry .= " OR `providers` LIKE '%".trim($companyName)."%' ";
        }            
        $i += 1;            
}    
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $qry); 
$companies = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);     
foreach ($companies as $companyName){
    echo $companyName;
}
```

[Here is result in second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL6qU.png)

Comment: may i know what the `c` refer to?

Comment: and where is the `$companies` and `$connection` comes?

Comment: c is table alias used for give temporary name.                                                       for more details => https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html                                                                                                          and $companies are coming from database

Comment: so i don't need a for loop to do that?

Comment: yes offcourse, if you want all matched companies name then it requires loop. did you want hole matched provider name( companies name )?

Comment: ya i want whole matched with provider name

Comment: btw do you want to see my updated question? I've posted the printed out query there, it might provide you a little more details

Comment: That you need to arrange as per your requirement here i give conceptual answer, hope easy to fit it in your requirement, i explained basic of sql query merged with php.

Comment: thx a lot dude, you saved my day, it works exactly as I wanted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198222/discussion-between-siddharth-and-overflow-stack).

Answer (score 1):

You can do in 2 ways.

1)

```
$array = explode(',', (trim($filters->input('provider'), '[]')));
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $query->where('providers', 'like', ['%' . $a . '%']);
    echo $a;
    echo $filters->input('provider');
}
```

Comment: @overflowstack It's the same code as yours but with a foreach. It does work if you implement it correct.

Comment: @overflowstack you may mark this correct answer, if its resolving your query.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan no, I cant get any data using these code

Comment: at line `echo $a` can you see some output or value ?

Comment: yes your code is same with my code, array stored the input but can't get result

Comment: please have a look on my updated question and check on the printed out query what query that we both have is
`select * from bonus_Company where bonuses.id = bonus_Company.fk_bonus_id and providers = ? and providers = ?` but the correct and logic query should be `select * from bonus_Company where bonuses.id = bonus_Company.fk_bonus_id and (providers like ? or providers like ?)`

Answer (score -1):

Best way to debug failing SQL queries is by looking at the query log:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog()

// code you want to debug

$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
print_r($queries);
```

Comment: Although you might be right, this Is hardly answer to the op's question...